# data consistent in a desktop application

Tags: java, orm, jdbc

I am trying to create a desktop application using eclipse-rcp. In that application, I use a ORM framework to load objects from database and using JFace-databinding to bind these objects to user-interface, so the users can modify data that these objects contains.

since the objects loaded, other users or other client may also work with the same data. so when user want to save the objects back into database, the data these objects contains may differs from data in database, the difference may be caused by my application or caused by others.

should I check against real data in database when I need to save a object that may be not fresh any more?

maybe this is a common problem in ORM, but this is first time I need to deal with ORM.

Comment: By the way: the exact same issue happens in web applications and pretty much everything that has a load-edit-save cycle. It's *not* specific to desktop applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - it's not a bad idea to check against "real" data before saving. you may have a special field - last update timestamp, or increment count.

such approach is called optimistic locking and, since it is very typical it may be supported by ORM's.